# Usage of "nimmer" merely poetic?

Tags: usage, poetry

I have read Bertold Brecht use "nimmer" to mean roughly "never" or "no more", for example in "Erinnerung an die Marie A.":

> Und als ich aufsah, war sie nimmer da.

Is this merely poetic license? Or can "nimmer" be used in more everyday contexts?

Comment: "nimmer" is a shortening of "nicht mehr" (not anymore). Using it identifies you as Southern German/Austrian.

Comment: The best translation, I think, is “nevermore”. And yes, in that sense it sounds quite poetic but see the answers for alternative usage.

Comment: Note that there is also "nimmermehr" which I would say is closer to "nevermore". "Nimmermehr" is used exclusively in poetic context.

Comment: @KonradRudolph it's also used as a short form of "nicht mehr" ... I've heard it used in Saxony, so not just Southern Germany or further South.

Comment: @Janka I have thought that is the shortening of "nie wieder"

Comment: Be aware, that "nimmer" has two different meanings. In standard German it means "never again", but in some dialects (and in the case of this poem as well) it means "nicht mehr", as @Janka already pointed out.

Answer (score 9):

It is quite an everyday word in Southern Germany and Austria.

https://www.dwds.de/wb/nimmer

Comment: Is considered to be part of the regional dialect, or just more frequently used there?

Comment: It is not dialect; it is used in the regional version of Standard German (Hochsprache).

Comment: @fdb, that "regional version" *is* a dialect (Bavarian in several variants). I would certainly not suggest to use "nimmer" to anyone who is not speaking those dialects fully. In Standard German (Hochsprache) it is certainly not frequent, you will never hear it on (serious) national newscasts etc.. Valid uses in certain sayings/words are given in the other answers.

Comment: @AnoE. We could discuss the difference between dialect and regional standard, but this is not really the place for it. “Nimmer” is part of the standard literary language of Old, Middle and New High German. There are lots of quotations from classical authors in verse and prose in the relevant entry in the “Grimm” dictionary. The poem by Brecht cited at the beginning of this thread is not composed in Augsburger dialect; it is standard literary German.

Comment: @fdb, ok, cutting technicalities then. The question is **Or can "nimmer" be used in more everyday contexts?** . It cannot, in modern German, except for certain edge cases (nie und nimmer etc.) and certain southern dialects, and your very short answer clearly implies that it can.

Answer (score 7):

There is this saying "*nie und nimmer*" to express that there is not the slightest possibility of something happening. As in

> Sie wird nie und nimmer so viel essen können.

She will never ever be able to eat that much.

This expression is commonly used.

Answer (score 3):

For your second question; *can "nimmer" be used in more everyday contexts?*

There is a made-up word with *nimmer* and it is used to express that something or an appointment will neven happen.

It is;

> Sankt-**Nimmer**leins-Tag

Some examples with this idiom;

> Auf einen Lotto-Sechser kannst du bis zum Sankt-Nimmerleins-Tag
> warten.
>
> Alle warten sehnsüchtig auf das Update, aber das kommt wohl
> erst am Sankt-Nimmerleins-Tag.